# Do I need both nss_ldap and pam_ldap?

Tags: authentication, pam, ldap, pam-ldap

This seems like a dumb question, but... do I need both nss_ldap and pam_ldap to have my users in LDAP?  It seems to me that pam_ldap would take care of pointing everything at the LDAP server as needed, and I don't know what nss_ldap adds for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

pam_ldap provides the authentication and authorization information for a user. nss_ldap provides the other user information that would be in /etc/passwd such as the uid, gid,home dir, gecos, and so on.

Comment: Oh, right.  I should have known that :(